# Element wise concat with two list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

I have 2 list of lists:

```
a = [['Apple'], ['Banana']]
b = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
```

How can I concatenate as strings element wise and get a new list of lists as below:

```
new_list = [['Apple1', 'Apple2', 'Apple3', 'Apple4'], ['Banana4', 'Banana5', 'Banana6']]
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `itertools.cycle`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import cycle

a = [['Apple'], ['Banana']] 
b = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6]]

result = [[m+str(n) for m, n in zip(cycle(i), j) ] for i,j in zip(a, b)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Apple1', 'Apple2', 'Apple3', 'Apple4'], ['Banana4', 'Banana5', 'Banana6']]
```

Answer (score 2):

One without `itertools`:

```
[["%s%s" % (i[0], n) for n in j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Output:

```
[['Apple1', 'Apple2', 'Apple3', 'Apple4'], ['Banana4', 'Banana5', 'Banana6']]
```

Answer (score 1):

can this help you?

```py
a = [['Apple'], ['Banana']]
b = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
print([
    [c + str(d) for d in j for c in i] for i, j in zip(a, b)
])
```

> ### Output:
>
> ```
> [['Apple1', 'Apple2', 'Apple3', 'Apple4'], ['Banana4', 'Banana5', 'Banana6']]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 2 `for` loops:

```
new_list = []
for [item], numbers in zip(a, b):
    item_list = []
    for n in numbers:
        item_list.append(f'{item}{n}')
    new_list.append(item_list)

new_list
```

**output:**

```
[['Apple1', 'Apple2', 'Apple3', 'Apple4'], ['Banana4', 'Banana5', 'Banana6']]
```

or you can use list comprehension:

```
[[f'{item}{n}' for n in numbers] for [item], numbers in zip(a, b)]
```